# python: unable to specify relative path for dll import

Tags: python, dll, import, loadlibrary

I am trying to load a dll in python, and can only do so if I enter the absolute path. I would like to use a relative path, or environment variables. The only thing that works is if I specify the exact path (C:...) I even tried to get the dll to build directly in the same folder as the py file, it still didn't work.
What I have:

```
MY_DLL = r'c:\full_path\output\Win32\Debug\my.dll'
#MY_DLL = r'my.dll'   #this doesn't work but it is what I want
#MY_DLL = r'$(env_var)\dir\output\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\my.dll'   #this doesn't work either but would be good too
```

Help ?

Comment: could you use `os.path.expandvars`?

Comment: I did from os import path
MY_DLL = os.path.expandvars(r'$(env_var)\dir\output\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\my.dll') But it showed that it is trying to load exactly what I put after the = and then NameError: 'os' is not defined. Sorry, clueless.. Did I put it in right ?

Comment: try `import os.path` instead of `from os import path`.  You also might need to change `$(env_var)` to `${env_var}` -- I'm not sure.  The name error is because you didn't import os, you imported path from os.  (the way you did it, os.path is known in your namespace as just path)

Comment: Thank you, it worked - but didn't expand the $(Configuration) and $(Platform). It is a lot more flexible than before. How do I mark that you have answered my question ?

Comment: I've posted an answer below -- You can click on the checkbutton below the number with the arrows above and below.  To expand Configuration and Platform, you should use the `${}` syntax (not `$()`) and they should expand too (as long as they're set in your environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about cdll on windows or really much about ctypes in general, however, you can manipulate paths quite easily using os.path:

```
import os.path
p1="path.dll"
print (os.path.abspath(p1))
p2="${env_var}/path.dll"  #Make sure you set env_var in the calling environment...Otherwise it won't be expanded...
print (os.path.expandvars(p2))
```